# Unirest Headers Request Body

Tags: java, curl, unirest, noaa

I've got a quick question about making a Unirest Request with headers.

I am using the NOAA API to access weather information.  They ask that you send a header with the following, but it is in CURL and I need help converting it to Java to make a Unirest Request:

```
curl -H "token:<token>" "url"
$.ajax({ url:<url>, data:{<data>}, headers:{ token:<token> } })
```

This is the URL of the documentation if it helps:
https://www.ncdc.noaa.gov/cdo-web/webservices/v2#gettingStarted

And here is the endpoint I am trying to access:
https://www.ncdc.noaa.gov/cdo-web/api/v2/datatypes/

This is probably something very simple, but I can't figure it out for the life of me!

### Thanks for the help in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unirest is actually not *that* daunting to work with. All you need to do is set a token value as header and you're set. You can use this snippet:

```
HttpResponse<JsonNode> response = null;

try {
    response = Unirest.get("https://www.ncdc.noaa.gov/cdo-web/api/v2/datatypes")
            .header("token", "YOUR_TOKEN_HERE")
            .asJson();
} catch (UnirestException e) {
    //Uh oh!
    e.printStackTrace();
}

System.out.println(response.getBody());
```

If you'd prefer to retrieve as a `String` instead you could replace `HttpResponse<JsonNode>` by `HttpResponse<String>` and `asJson()` by `asString()`.

You can find much more useful information [here](http://unirest.io/java).